# Magento 2: How to add a condition to product list in backend?

Tags: magento2

Magento version: 2.0
In backend, I plan to add a new condition from a custom table to the product list and then get a new list of product. 
how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I reckon that you've probably found the answer to the question, but here it's what I think:

For adding a new condition to a custom table, you have to go to Stores and then, under the Settings section, there is the Terms and Conditions option. There you can add the condition that can apply to the specific list.